# Can I open a REPL in the context of a Spring Web Application?

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, tomcat, read-eval-print-loop

I'm working on a web application based on Spring MVC and Hibernate on Tomcat 8 (both for deployment and local development). The IDE is Spring Tool Suite (which is based on Eclipse).

I want to open a REPL (read-eval-print-loop, like Groovy's, Python's, Ruby's, etc) in the context of my application (while it's running on Tomcat locally), to speed up development by shortening the code -> test feedback loop.

That is, I want to be able to open a shell in the command line (or inside Eclipse) and do something like:

```
ClientDAO clientDAO = getAutowiredDAOFromSpringSomehow();
Client client = clientDAO.findByID(100);
client.setName("Another name");
clientDAO.save(client);
```

I can work around this a bit by setting a breakpoint somewhere in a controller and use Eclipse's debugger Display tab to execute arbitrary code, but this is a bit impractical and uncomfortable.

I'm open to using Groovy or Scala's shell if it's more convenient (I obviously still need access to my objects, though).

What are my options?

Comment: I know you ruled out the Display tab, but for those looking for it, Spring Tool Suite calls it "Debug Shell".

Answer (score 3):

You may be able to do it using [Spring Shell](https://docs.spring.io/spring-shell/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#d4e260), [JShell](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/jshell/introduction-jshell.htm#JSHEL-GUID-630F27C8-1195-4989-9F6B-2C51D46F52C8) or [BeanShell](https://github.com/beanshell/beanshell)

[Here's a project](https://github.com/zhanghai/BeeShell) to embed a repl in an android app using BeanShell

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's useful for your use-case but theoretically it should be possible to do this using [CRaSH](http://www.crashub.org/). It's a Shell like Bash on Linux but for your Java-Application and it's possible to create your own commands.

Comment: I tried to have CRaSH setup in my app to try to see if it offers some sort of REPL loop, but still could not get it running. Any documentation to do that?

Comment: [This link](http://www.crashub.org/1.3/reference.html#_embedding_in_spring) should guide you to configure it the right way :) You can then use the [groovy plugin](http://www.crashub.org/1.3/reference.html#_the_groovy_repl) to execute any code you want.